# SSH shell on a multicore supercomputer

Tags: linux, ssh, shell, java, scp

I created a program on my 2 core laptop and I want to verify how my program performs when more than 2 cores are available for processing.

Do anybody knows any free (or cheap) service where I can have for a limited time a SSH shell account to run my program for some tests?

My program is written in Java, so I would need also the JRE installed on the server, but nothing more, since I can test the processing on the command line after scp-ing the jar file on the server; don't even need disk space or anything else, since the computation is done in memory.

Comment: You could use any multicore VPS, of which there are many. If you just need a cheap one for testing and don't care about performance or reliability, see http://lowendbox.com. Don't try to use them for production, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Systems with 4, 8, or even 12 cores or more are not all that uncommon these days, and they aren't normally called "supercomputers" -- that moniker is reserved these days for systems with *many thousands* of cores. If it only takes an hour or two to run your test, you can run it on Amazon EC2 On-demand instance and just pay as you go; to see it run on a high-end server with a lot of resources (RAM and many CPU cores), you could go with one of the more expensive servers.

If you wanted to test it on a whole bunch of cores, then at the price of $2.40 per hour, you could start up a Linux system with full root access, install the JRE, and run your code, on a virtual system with 32 "cores" -- in practice these may end up being actually 16 physical cores with hyperthreading, or something like that, but the concept is the same.

It's much cheaper per hour if you get a smaller system with, say, 4 cores -- 30 cents an hour.

[EC2 Pricing](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/). Definitely cheaper than paying an entire month or more for a VPS, if you can complete your tests in around 1 - 8 hours or so. If you need to test over the long long term (months, with continuous uptime 24/7), a VPS where you pay a flat fee every month is more suitable, or go with an EC2 High Utilization instance where you pay up-front and get a discount on the per-hour rate.